# Hugo custom article link: link that starts the article from the end of the summary

Tags: go, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I wonder how it is possible to generate an article link that instead of pointing to the `{{ .RelPermalink }}` (permanent link of the article page), it points to a certain paragraph or text.

For example, it may point to the sentence that contains the 71th word (because by default, `{{ .Summary }}` includes text up to 70 words), or maybe the second paragraph of the article (for people that have the summary set to be the first paragraph).

This would be useful because if the readers click into the article after browsing from the main page and reading the summary or first paragraph, then when they click "expand"/"read full", then would be able to just pick-off from where they left off.

I'm fairly new to this tool and have been consistently fascinated by Hugo and Go. I look forward to learning and elegant approach that leverages Hugo's strengths, but would be humbly open to all possible solutions or critiques to my objective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your probably want to use anchor links.

Expand your URL to `{{ .RelPermalink }}#endofsummary`

Then you have to add the anchor tag `<a name="endofsummary">` at the correct position in your destination page.

Afaik there is no HUGO way to do it.